# Specialize template with a subclass of an abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class, subclass

I'm stuck with the following issue:

I've got a class `Test` with template `T`. When I create an object of this class, specializing with other common class, everything works fine. In the constructor of class `Test` there is one line of code which creates an object of the template class;

But when I try to instantiate this class (`Test`), specializing it with a subclass (`SubDummy`) of an abstract class (`Dummy`), I get an error: cannot instantiate an abstract class.

Example code (simplified to the purpose of this post):

```
class Dummy
{
private:
    virtual void _nothing() = 0;    // this makes the class abstract
};

class SubDummy : public Dummy
{
public:
    SubDummy() :
        Dummy()
    {
    }
};

template <class T>
    class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    {
        T t;    // here the compiler reports the error
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test<SubDummy> x;
}
```

Comment: `SubDummy` is still an abstract class unless you override `_nothing`

Comment: @PiotrS. Clear! Put your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I would accept [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27567740/3953764)

Comment: `// here the compiler reports the error` - Could you please add the actual compiler's message as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Classes containing pure virtual member functions simply cannot be instantiated. Since you didn't specify an override for `_nothing` in `SubDummy`, it is a pure virtual in this class as well. You must implement `_nothing` in `SubDummy` in order to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, when debugging templates it's useful to think of what the class becomes when you instantiate it with the variables.

```
    class TestWithSubDummy {
       public:
           TestWithSubDummy() {
                 SubDummy t;//the error
            }
     };
```

You are pretty obviously trying to instantiate a `SubDummy` (using the default constructor) at the error. But `SubDummy` is abstract, so we aren't allowed to instantiate it. Thus, the error.